# Can't update Firebase database object using snap.val()

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All I want to do is update a property on the `snap.val()`, to update my Firebase database.

```
function updateListItem(listItem) {
  var dbRef = firebase.database()
    .ref()
    .child('userdb')
    .child($scope.user.uid)
    .child(listItem.taskid);

  dbRef.on('value', snap => {
    var task = snap.val()
    console.log(task);
    //update object property here?
  });
}
```

I'm really new to Firebase so any advice is appreciated as well. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: snap.val() only gets the value, you need update/setValue/push to write data to Firebase. [See the docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mjr, you pointed a out a huge flaw in how i was visualizing firebase. :)

```
  var dbRef = firebase.database()
      .ref()
      .child('userdb')
      .child($scope.user.uid)
      .child(listItem.taskid)
      .set({title: 'thisworks', in_folder: 'main', is_complete: false});
}
```